# How do I list roles using ENUM?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

Example of a POST request that I will make to add a user: `Vasya, Petrenko,910382741, vasya@mail.ru, ADMIN` the first 4 attributes work, but I don't understand how to make a field for a role.

Is my database built correctly? I use Json to send a request to add a user, the user's relationship to the role is many to many. I don't understand how to send the role, I need another attribute in the user?

```
UserController

private UserRepository userRepository;

    public UserController(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }


@PostMapping
public String userPostAdd(@RequestBody User user) {
    List<Authority> rolesList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Role role : user.getRole()){
        Authority r = role.getName();
        if (r != null){
            rolesList.add(r);
        }
    }

    if (!rolesList.isEmpty()){
        userRepository.save(user);
    }
    return "Add user";
}
```

Entity Role

```
@ToString
@Entity
@Table(name = "role", schema = "task")
public class Role {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Authority name;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "role")
private List<User> users;

getter,setter...

}
```

User:

```
@ToString
@Entity
@Table(name = "user", schema = "task")
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "user_role",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
private List<Role> role;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
private Set<Contract> contract;

@Column(name = "surname", nullable = false)
private String surname;
@Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
private String name;
@Column(name = "email", nullable = false, unique = true)
private String email;
@Column(name = "phone", nullable = false, unique = true)
private Integer phone;

getter,setter...

}
```

Enum

```
public enum Authority {
    TENANT ("tenant"),
    LANDLORD ("landlord"),
    ADMIN ("admin");

    private final String name;

    private Authority(String s) {
        name = s;
    }

    public boolean equalsName(String otherName) {
        return name.equals(otherName);
    }

    public String toString() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you do sth like this? https://github.com/gtiwari333/spring-boot-web-application-seed/tree/single-module-no-keycloak/src/main/java/gt/app/domain Note that the Role is called Authority in this code. Also note this is in a separate branch `single-module-no-keycloak`

Comment: @gtiwari333 In General, I have prepared the ENUM class, but I don't know exactly how to check roles. He couldn't find where it was located. Its code is quite complex for me, because there are too many folders and branches

Comment: Its not that complex :) Can you share your code so that we can look into?

Comment: @gtiwari333 yep: https://github.com/Blacit/TaskSpring I didn't even notice that it was your repository) I want to say that I was very surprised by it, I liked writing the code. I dream and strive to do the same in the future)

Comment: In your Role entity class do this to use the enum ```@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Roles name;```

Comment: Also you have to pre-configure the Role table with those three roles and provide a list of Roles enum  in your request and map that to the db object. Or expect the user to send the roles with db IDs

Comment: I have a question, I did as you said, added this field, but all the others turned red because I'm already using name. Should I delete this line? `private final String name;`

Comment: yes. We are changing String name to Roles name

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't quite understand the last one, but how do I make a table with 3 roles? Do you mean that you need to create a new table with 3 attributes: admin, tenant, and landlord? And how to compare it with the role table later?

Comment: Also, its better to rename the class `Roles` to something else since we already have `Role` class

Comment: `@Table(name = "role", schema = "task")
public class Role {` you already have role table. What i am saying is you might need create three rows in this table before you can create User records.

Comment: @gtiwari333 Is my database built correctly? I use Json to send a request to add a user, the user's relationship to the role is many to many. I don't understand how to send the role, I need another attribute in the user? Code updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're setting `roles = null` and then make a method call on it. You first need to fetch the role object by calling `valueOf`. If the role does not exist it should be null. The following should work.

```
@PostMapping
public String userPostAdd(@ModelAttribute User user) {
    List<Roles> rolesList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Role role : user.getRole()){
        Roles r = Roles.valueOf(role.getName().toUpperCase());
        if (r != null){
            rolesList.add(r)
        } 
    }
    
    if (!rolesList.isEmpty()){
       userRepository.save(user);
    } 
    return "Add user";
}
```

Comment: Cannot resolve method 'toUpperCase' in 'Role'. Instead of Roles, I have Authority, and instead of requestUserDetails, we should save user, as I understand it

Comment: I updated again. Also, you're using very ambiguous class and variable names. Why would you define the enum as Roles and not RoleEnum and same for a list of roles, which you defined as `Role`. It's very confusing and makes it difficult for the community to help you

Comment: To avoid confusion, I changed Authority now instead of Roles. I have ; missing after relosList.add(r); the Program still doesn't work, returns the error Cannot resolve method 'toUpperCase' in 'Authority'. IDEA suggests creating a toUpperCase method in Authority

Comment: Then why don't you update your code? I'm still not sure whether you changed `Roles` or `Role` to `Authority`? Also, did you define any getters in your `Role` class?

Comment: Is my database built correctly? I use Json to send a request to add a user, the user's relationship to the role is many to many. I don't understand how to send the role, I need another attribute in the user? Code updated.